# Communicating UI Thread not usings View.post in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-handler

I have a question when it comes to views you can easily use `View.post` but example
how about in adapter like `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` you cant use the view.post,

example im updating my listview which is more best practice of using from this codes

```
mAdapter = new HomePageAdapter(this, list);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Which of this style is best practice:

runOnUiThread

```
 mAdapter = new HomePageAdapter(this, list);

HomePage.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

AsyncTask

```
class updates extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            mAdapter = new HomePageAdapter(HomePage.this, defaultListVal);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Handler

```
handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
          mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
          mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
 };

class update implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mAdapter = new HomePageAdapter(HomePage.this, defaultListVal);

        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're updating a `ListView`, why not use a `Loader`?

Comment: is loader good practice in com the UI thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of them have different functionality:

```
Which of this style is best practice:
```

**runOnUiThread**

Use this when only if you are on different thread that is because a thread that create this view can only call/update that view, if you are updating it on a different thread without calling its parent thread then you will get a `CalledFromWrongThreadException`

**AsyncTask**

Use this when you are doing a Network Connection, hard work on the CPU, etc. that will block the main thread.

**Handler**

Same as the `runOnUiThread` it will call the main thread, `Handler` are always called by its parent Thread where you instantiate it.

Comment: thanks Rod_Algonguin for you advice :)